# Why (1UL <<53) plus 1.0 does not equal to itself?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Say

```
int64_t x = (1UL << 53);
cout << x << end;
x+= 1.0;
cout << x << end;
```

The result of x is same, which is '9007199254740992'.

However, `x += 1;` can make x plus 1 correctly.

Moreover, for `1UL << 52` plus 1.0 can make the result correctly.

I think it could be the float imprecision. Could someone give me more details of that?

Answer (score 3):

The line `x+= 1.0` is evaluated as

```
x = (int64_t)((double)x + (double)1.0);
```

The number `2^53 + 1 = 9007199254740993` can't be represented exactly as IEEE `double`, so it's rounded to `2^53 = 9007199254740992` (this depends on the current rounding mode, actually) which is then (losslessly) converted to an `int64_t`.

Answer (score 2):

```
x+= 1.0;
```

The expression `x + 1.0` is done with floating point arithmetic.

Assuming [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is used, the [double precision floating point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) can represent integers at most  2<sup>53</sup> precisely.